# iosアプリのリリース申請のエラー

Tags: ios, unity3d

Unityで作成したゲームをデバッグし、x-code上でArchiveし、Archiveビルドが作成されValidateボタンを押したら、
「iTunes Store operation failed.
No suitable application records were found Verify your bundle identifier 'boundle name' is correct」というエラーで成功しません。

このエラーの解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

ご自分のアカウントで、itunesconnectに、ログインして、そのappが、waiting for upload になってますか？　なってなければ、そういうエラーは、出るべくして出ます。　
　itunesconnect側で、AppStore用スクリーンショット、Appの説明文などのメタデータを入力して、waiting for uploadの状態にすることが必要です。

Comment: または、waiting for uploadになっているもののbundleIDと違うbundleIDがセットされているのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

itunes connectってサイトで先に＋を押さないとダメですね